# How to remove midpoints from a line in StarUML

Tags: uml, staruml

I can't figure out any way to select a specific midpoint and delete it.  I can of course delete the entire line and create a new one, which is my workaround thus far, but a way to actually remove midpoints would be less cumbersome.  Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The midpoint is removed automatically when you move it in such a way that both the associated segments are more-or-less in line.

[image]